# 3 dot button appears in emulator but not in devie

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

I was testing my app with an emulator and my 3 dot button was displayed perfectly.

When I tested with my real device ( Samsung Galaxy S3), those 3 dot button never appeared, and I don't know why. Instead I'm getting all 3 buttons , and I only wanted 1 + the 3 dot buttons...

Here's my menu

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_add"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add"
    android:title="Ajouter Cours"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_setting"
        android:title="Réglages"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_setting"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        />
    <item

        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:title="Se déconnecter"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_logout"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        />
```

Here's the OnCreate and SelectedItem methods

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_affichage_notes,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.action_logout:
            //création d'un Intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(AffichageNotes.this, PageAccueil.class);
            //ajout de fonctionnalités qui vont être transférés
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
            //transfert aussi de la valeur EXIT qui est true
            intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_setting:
            Intent a = new Intent(AffichageNotes.this,Reglages.class);
            startActivity(a);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_add:
            Intent i = new Intent(AffichageNotes.this,AjoutTexte.class);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            int id = getIntent().getIntExtra("id",0);
            i.putExtra("id",id);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Where does the error come from ? Thank you guys !

Answer (score 0):

Did you put your items inside a menu?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_add"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add"
    android:title="Ajouter Cours"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_setting"
        android:title="Réglages"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_setting"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        />
    <item

        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:title="Se déconnecter"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_logout"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        />

</menu>
```

Edit: to make solution visible

```
  try {
      ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
      FieldmenuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuK‌​ey");
      if (menuKeyField != null) {

        menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
        menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      return;
    }
```

Comment: @David Can you see the action bar? Maybe you can't see because of your theme, can you post your style.xml file please?

Comment: Found the solution !

` try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if(menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Ignore
    }`